# Backbone deep model setting atttibutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to use  [backbone deep model] (https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model) for the Person model which have nested attributes. The example code in github shows to set nested attributes like names

```
 model.set({
    'user.name.first': 'Lana',
    'user.name.last':  'Kang'
});
```

but how to set model attributes otherSpies.name[0]:'Lana' ?

JSON format of my person model shown below.

```
  {
    "birthdate": "2005-10-26T00:00:00.000+0530",
    "gender": "M",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "value": "saagar.gugwad@gmail.com",
            "attributeType": "8d6d7f78-9b9e-409a-96dc-ea8300e54175"
        },
        {
            "value": "single",
            "attributeType": "6b550dd7-ce73-4f14-af2d-35d1a37e7377"
        },
        {
            "value": "7829730769",
            "attributeType": "d1266776-7431-4fa4-9724-215c21418efb"
        },
        {
            "value": "0",
            "attributeType": "892089d1-f187-404b-89c3-96606194a05c"
        },
        {
            "value": "AAAAAACAGwEtAAHMpTgHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\n",
            "attributeType": "d5ac7b1d-a563-4661-9d9d-0ad6b8e346e8"
        }
    ],
    "addresses": [
        {
           "address1":"bla",
           "address2":"bla2",
           "street"  :"walstreet",
           "pincode" :"222FB"
        }
    ],
    "names": [
        {
            "familyName": "Dbh",
            "givenName": "Saagar"
        }
    ],
    "age": 8
}
```

I want to set attributes using my personModel. How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: Ive never used this library before but it shows that you get array'd model attributes by doing: `model.get('otherSpies.0.name')`. To me it would make sense to be able to set it like `model.set('otherSpies.0.name','something')`

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder/issues/56

Comment: Thank you it helped. I might prefer to use model.get('attributes').at(0).set('value', 'bla');